# Outlook creates a new calendar tab for an ICS file with mutiple VEVENTS

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, icalendar

I have two questions about .ics files and outlook:

1) I have an asp.net page that gets the meeting details from the database and put them in an ICS file. If there is only 1 meeting, Outlook allows the .ics file to create a new calendar appointment under my calendar. However, when there are multiple meetings in 1 .ics file, outlook creates a new separate calendar tab to show all the meetings in that .ics files.

How to I make outlook to import all multiple meetings in an .ics file to my calendar as opposed to a new tab?

2) For the single meeting ics file, how do I prevent outlook to add duplicate to the calendar when I double click on the ics file multiple times?

I did set a `UID` as `"UID:uid" + meetingid + "@ourcompany.com"` inside `VEVENT`.

Thanks,

Comment: I would really like to know the answer to question 1.

EDIT: Found something in related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334334/how-to-create-a-ics-file-with-multiple-vevents-to-be-imported-into-an-existing?rq=1