# Have ICS file with multiple events save to my Calendar, not Other Calendars

Tags: calendar, outlook, icalendar

When I convert my Excel spreadsheet to a CSV file... then convert my CSV file into an ICS file... I can open the ICS file with a single event inside, and accept the meeting invitation, which is then added to my calendar.

(Using this app for the conversion) http://icsconverterwebapp.n8henrie.com/

[image]

The problem is, if I put multiple rows in my Excel spreadsheet, the final ICS version opens as an "Other Calendars"

Can I make it so that the ICS file items are added to my Calendar, and not "Other Calendars"?

**I've read online that this seems to be common... not just unique to the web app being used.**

[image]

---

Here is what the .ical looks like when opened up in notepad

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:n8henrie.com
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE

TZID:Eastern Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE

BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":20140207T073000
DTEND;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":20140207T080000
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20140131T201152Z
UID:95411648482978418158407727822520140131T201152___n8henrie.com
DESCRIPTION:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
LOCATION:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT


BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":20140207T080000
DTEND;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":20140207T090000
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20140131T201152Z
UID:94761546274544960391869215468820140131T201152___n8henrie.com
DESCRIPTION:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
LOCATION:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

Comment: can you share the details of your ical file? for instance METHOD:PUBLISH vs METHOD:REQUEST can make big differences

Comment: @oberron no problem. on OP.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answers.microsoft.com response](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/icalics-files-creating-new-calendar-instead-of/60ee1860-4654-4487-943f-8e9146791ea7) this is the expected behaviour of Outlook when opening a .ics file with multiple events since Outlook 2003.

According to the response you can manually import the .ics file by following these steps:

> 1. Go to the default calendar
> 2. Click on file
> 3. Select open & export
> 4. Select import/ export file
> 5. Under import/ export wizard select import an icalendar file
> 6. Select the file to be import from the saved location
> 7. Check with the outlook default calendar

Apparently the behaviour you expect can be achieved through an internet calendar but I have not tested this. See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538017/1208040) for how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I create the events in the calendar app on MacOS, I select them in the calendar and then I export them from: File -> Export -> Export...

Here is an example of an .ics file that adds 2 events:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Event 1Access-A-Ride Pickup
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20231116T103400
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20231116T110400
LOCATION:1000 Broadway Ave.\, Brooklyn
DESCRIPTION: Event 1 Access-A-Ride to 900 Jay St.\, Brooklyn
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:3
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT10M
DESCRIPTION:Pickup Reminder
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Event 2 Access-A-Ride Pickup
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20231115T200000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20231115T203000
LOCATION: Brooklyn
DESCRIPTION: Event 2 Access-A-Ride to 1000 Broadway Ave.\, Brooklyn
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:3
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT10M
DESCRIPTION:Pickup Reminder
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Would you be able to share the content of the export that is generated?  Maybe one can see some special aspect that makes it work.

Comment: @Jus Sure, I updated my answer with the output of the calendar file.