# Opening ICS file with multiple events creates new calendar in Outlook

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I would like to be able to create an ICS file **with multiple events** that user will be able to import in their **default** Exchange Calendar. I need to support Outlook desktop client, Office 365 web interface and Apple iPhone Mail/Calendar.

Note that issue only occurs with ICS files that contain multiple events. Single event ICS works as expected.

Following multi-event ICS file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//bobbin v0.1//NONSGML iCal Writer//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180327T080000Z
DTEND:20180327T110000Z
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003a@yourserver.com
CREATED:20091130T213238Z
DESCRIPTION:Example event 1
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Example event 1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180328T120000Z
DTEND:20180328T130000Z
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003b@yourserver.com
CREATED:20091130T213238Z
DESCRIPTION:Example event 2
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Example event 2
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

works fine in Office 365 web interface and Apple iPhone Mail/Calendar. However, when it is imported in Outlook 2016 it creates a new "Untitled" Calendar and puts events in it instead of default user calendar.

This seems to be a known issue referenced previously on SO:

[ICal import creates new calendar When Open the ics file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212329/ical-import-creates-new-calendar-when-open-the-ics-file)

[Have ICS file with multiple events save to my Calendar, not Other Calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484689/have-ics-file-with-multiple-events-save-to-my-calendar-not-other-calendars)

Answers range from "it cannot be done" to the opposite.

One of the posts in the first link mentions removing  `X-WR-CALNAME` from ICS fixes the problem. I never had this in ICS to begin with.

Another post on the same page mentions that adding `X-WR-RELCALID:XXXXXX` fixes it. I tried putting it in and it makes no difference at all. I am not sure if value for X-WR-RELCALID should be set to something specific - I just set it to some GUID.

If someone successfully resolved it - can you post an ICS sample and what version of Outlook did it work with?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I never resolved the issue. In our case we ended up using MS Exchange API and impersonation to create meetings directly in attendee calendar. We treated multi-day meetings as several single day meetings. NOTE: be careful using impersonation because it allows impersonating account COMPLETE access to everything in mailbox and calendar, you can't limit it to calendar only which is a bad design IMO.

Comment: Same problem here